# Tikz: Lebesgue curve / Z curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to draw a [Z curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) (Lebesgue curve) by using [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/hilbert-curve/) example for Hilbert curves. But I don't see why it does not work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[position=top,labelformat=empty]{subfig}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newdimen\HilbertLastX
\newdimen\HilbertLastY
\newcounter{HilbertOrder}

\def\DrawToNext#1#2{%
   \advance \HilbertLastX by #1
   \advance \HilbertLastY by #2
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\HilbertLastX}{\HilbertLastY}}
}

% \Hilbert[right_x,right_y,left_x,left_x,up_x,up_y,down_x,down_y]
\def\Hilbert[#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8] {
  \ifnum\value{HilbertOrder} > 0%
     \addtocounter{HilbertOrder}{-1}
     \Hilbert[#5,#6,#7,#8,#1,#2,#3,#4]
     \Hilbert[#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8]
     \DrawToNext {#1} {#5}
     \Hilbert[#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8]
     \DrawToNext {#3} {#3}
     \Hilbert[#7,#8,#5,#6,#3,#4,#1,#2]
     \DrawToNext {#1} {#5}
     \addtocounter{HilbertOrder}{1}
  \fi
}

\def\hilbert((#1,#2),#3){%
   \advance \HilbertLastX by #1
   \advance \HilbertLastY by #2
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\HilbertLastX}{\HilbertLastY}}
   \setcounter{HilbertOrder}{#3}
   \Hilbert[1mm,0mm,-1mm,0mm,0mm,1mm,0mm,-1mm]
   \pgfusepath{stroke}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat[$n=1$]{\tikz[scale=18] \hilbert((0mm,0mm),1);}~~
    \subfloat[$n=2$]{\tikz[scale=6] \hilbert((0mm,0mm),2);}~~
    \subfloat[$n=3$]{\tikz[scale=2.6] \hilbert((0mm,0mm),3);}~~
    \subfloat[$n=4$]{\tikz[scale=1.2] \hilbert((0mm,0mm),4);}~~
    \subfloat[$n=5$]{\tikz[scale=0.58] \hilbert((0mm,0mm),5);}%
\end{figure}%

\end{document}
```

I get this result which is obviously wrong: [image]

Any suggestions how to make it work? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a way using the `lindenmayersystems` library. Orders above `8` will take *ages*:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{z-curve}{
\symbol{I}{\pgftransformscale{+0.25\pgflsystemstep}}
\symbol{p}{%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{3pt}}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{1pt}}%
}
\symbol{q}{%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{3pt}}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{1pt}}%
}
\symbol{S}{\pgftransformscale{+0.5pt}}
\symbol{A}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{4pt}}}
\symbol{B}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{4pt}}}
\symbol{C}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{0pt}}}
\symbol{[}{\bgroup}
\symbol{]}{\egroup}
\rule{Z -> Ip}
\rule{p -> S[Ap][Bq][q][Cq]}
\rule{q -> S[Aq][Bq][q][Cq]}
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,9}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\draw [draw=red] (0,0) rectangle (5,5) (2.5, 5) node [above] {order: \i};
\draw [l-system={z-curve, step=5cm, axiom=Z, order=\i}] l-system;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I place the first four orders horizontal side by side? In addition I get an error if I try it using `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}`.  But why?

Comment: @Samuel the error is due to the fact that the `tikz` package was automatically included by the `standalone` class due to the `tikz` option. If the document class is changed then `\usepackage{tikz}` needs to be added to the preamble. To reposition the z-curve use the `shift` key as the first argument to the `\draw` command e.g., \draw `[shift={(5,0)}, l-system={...`

Comment: I would like to use your approach also for Hilbert Curves. Since I do not really understand how your code works I would like to know how it works and how I can modify it in order to get Hilbert curves. That would be great!

Comment: This may be very impressive, but all I see is a solid black square with `order: 9` above it. Is this supposed to illustrate something or is it a problem with my browser? Images sometimes disappear, but I've never known one turn into a black hole before!

Comment: @cfr There's a high density of lines hence the whole square is filled. I'm not sure what's your question because it seems pretty obvious to me (may be I'm wrong?).

Comment: @Manuel This time, I saw the animation. When I wrote that comment, I'd only seen the last frame. I didn't know that there were 8 before it. So, as far as I saw, there was just a black square which did not seem very useful as an illustration of anything.