# TikZ: Z-order curve (Lebesgue curve) with Lindenmayer systems

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a [Z-order curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) witz TikZ using the Lindenmayer systems. This is kind of hard since this curve consists of paths with changing angels. And it seems to me, that the only angle I can change is `angle=135`. So I did not find a way to draw a Z-order curve. Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\usetikzlibrary[shadings]

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Lebesgue curve}{
  \rule{L -> F+F-FR}
  \rule{R -> F+F-F}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shadedraw [bottom color=white, top color=white, draw=black]
[l-system={Lebesgue curve, step=20pt, angle=135, axiom=L, order=2}]
lindenmayer system;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I get is this:

[image]

Does not really looks like a [Z-order curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve). I really want to use `\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}`. Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: Probably there is the same question at your site http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347601/tikz-lebesgue-curve-z-curve.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Right, but this here is an other way to do it and probably much easier once there is a good solution.

Comment: Those angels - if only they'd stay put a minute, you might be able to tell your archangels from your heralds. It just isn't fair.

Comment: How does this differ from your earlier question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347601/, which has an answer from Mark Wibrow using the library you specify in your desiderata here?

Comment: I say duplicate. If the answer in your first question is not satisfaying to you, edit the question and then **open up a bounty** and check if anyone is interested in providing another answer. As this question stands I believe it to be a dead on duplicate.